# Multiplication of two multidimensional arrays in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Is there any predefined function in Anylogic to return the multiplication of two similar multidimensional arrays? So, the resulted multidimensional array have the same dimension. I found Multiply() and prod() but they didn't work. If not what's the best way? I can write the function in Matlab and call it from Anylogic but it decelerates the model hugely.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RNMF.png)

Answer (score 0):

This example model shows you how to use an external package to multiply matrices, hope this helps: https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/ec631da6-f048-4e94-b804-33d65002a796?mode=SETTINGS